# How to do incremental summing in same column with Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column [Sales Growth] which as five rows (say for 5 months). Where current row = 1.05% of preceding row or previous row. And it continues down with each new row.

In Excel its very easy Suppose I am in B2 all I have to do is B1*1.05. But, in Power Query, it turned out to be very difficult to solve. I have seen all kinds of solutions with double indexing and Index -1 etc which is good for running total but not in my case.

[image: Example from Excel for problem description. Same needs to be achieved in Power Query]

Comment: Why are the running total solutions not suitable. This is just a running multiplication.

Comment: It is different. In classic running total solutions using Index columns, you can add up all previous rows to get total for the current row and move on. Here, you only need just the preceding or previous row, multiply it with a percentage point. If I use a helper column with (1) in all rows so I could jump back to previous row ({-1} [Index]), it always gives me back 1st row. Not the previous row. That is what proving to be difficult.

Comment: OK, I'll add an answer to show what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are looking to do. But if you start with some base number and always increase each row by the same % then its just a math compounding formula.

```
Result = Base * (1+Rate)^PeriodNumber
```

or in powerquery terms,

```
= Base * Number.Power(1+Rate,[Column_Containing_Period])
```

sample code:

```
let
Starting=100,
Growth=.05,
Source =  Table.FromList({0..50}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Index"}, null, ExtraValues.Error ),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Starting*Number.Power(1+Growth,[Index]))
in #"Added Custom"
```

or

```
let
Starting=100,
Growth=.05,
Source =  List.Transform({0..50}, each Starting*Number.Power(1+Growth,_)),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Result"}, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in #"Converted to Table"
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Number.Power, great. It worked. I want to paste my results here but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Query 1

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlSK1QGSegameBmxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Factor = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Factor", type number}}),
    BF = List.Buffer(#"Changed Type"[Factor]),
    Result = Table.FromColumns(
        {   
            #"Changed Type"[Factor], fx(BF)
        },
        {
            "Factor",
            "Result"
        }

    )



in
    Result
```

Relevant Function

```
(values as list) as list =>

let 

result = List.Generate(

    () => [result = 100, counter = 0],
    each [counter] < List.Count(values),
    each [result = [result] * values{[counter] + 1}, counter = [counter]+1 ],
    each [result]

)

in result
```

Comment: Thank you David. Your help came first. But, it is complicated for someone like me to understand and use it. But, I promise you I will learn it and implement it. Thank you man!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark a solution as future viewers.